# How to measure Syntactic Similarity between a query and a document?

Tags: text, syntax, nlp, similarity

Is there a way to measure the syntactic similarity between a query (sentence) and a document (a set of sentences)?

Comment: yes. But if you want a more specific answer, you're going to have to make your question more specific. (what have you searched for already? what did you expect to find, what did you find instead, whathaveyoutried.com, things that show you did everything you could to find the answer on your own, but couldn't find it)

Comment: Actually I've read some in tree kernels and comparing the syntactic tree for 2 sentences. But I can't conclude how to use this basic idea in query document similarity. And will it really provide logical results !!

Comment: It would make sense to measure the syntactic similarity between the query and each separate sentence in the document, i.e. looking to retrieve sentences that are most similar to the query, not entire documents. There is a field called Question Answering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) that aims to do just that, and, AFAIK, syntactic similarity is being used for QA.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using [deep linguistic processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linguistic_processing) tools that involves deep grammars like [HPSG](http://moin.delph-in.net/) and LFG? If you're looking in to feature based syntax similarity you can take a look at [Kenji Sagae and Andrew S. Gordon](http://people.ict.usc.edu/~gordon/ssrp.html)'s work on calculating syntactic similarity of verbs using PropBank and then clustering the similar verbs to improve HPSG grammar.

To have a simpler approach I suggest just looking at dependency parses and group sentences with the same parse nodes. Or just POS tag sentences and compare sentences with same POS tags.

For the sake of an simple example, first download and install NLTK (http://nltk.org/) and the hunpos tagger (http://code.google.com/p/hunpos/). Unzip the en_wsj.model.gz and save it at where you python script will be.

```
import nltk 
from nltk.tag.hunpos import HunposTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

s1 = "This is a short sentence"
s2 = "That is the same sentence"

ht = HunposTagger('en_wsj.model')
print ht.tag(word_tokenize(corpus))http://nltk.org/

# Tag the sentences with HunPos
t1 = ht.tag(word_tokenize(s1))
t2 = ht.tag(word_tokenize(s2))

#Extract only the POS tags
pos1 = [i[1] for i in t1]
pos2 = [j[1] for j in t2]

if pos1 == pos2:
    print "same sentence according to POS tags"
else:
    print "diff sentences according to POS tags"
```

This script above outputs:

```
>>> print pos1
['DT', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN']
>>> print pos2
['DT', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN']
>>> if pos1 == pos2:
...     print "same sentence according to POS tags"
... else:
...     print "diff sentences according to POS tags"
... 
same sentence according to POS tags
```

To modify the above code, try:

- instead of comparing POS use dependency parses
- instead of a strict list compare, come up with some statistical methods to measure level of differences

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)?