# TEXT - How to break a paragraph into smaller sentence (No indication of End of Sentence)

Tags: python, text, analytics, text-analysis

I am using both `R` and `Python` and trying to learn Text based analytics and `NLP` to some extent.

**Question**: How do I split a sentence which is a mix of sentences like below

Sentence = I like the application i like the system i do not like the process being followed.

I want to split this sentence into

1. I like the application
2. i like the system
3. i do not like the process being followed

**Note:** I am able to split a sentence like below as it has a `.` to indicate end of a sentence

Sentence = I like the application. I like the system.  I do not like the process being followed.

Vj

Answer (score 1):

I can propose an approach that can help you, since you don't have sentence delimiter, you can proceed as follow:

- Apply a syntactic analyzing to extract the syntactic nature of the paragraph.

  **Example:**  I like the application i like the system i do not like the process being followed

  will produce: PP VB DT NN...

  To extract the syntactic analyzing I recommend to use [Stanford Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml).

  PP: Personal Pronoun

  VB: VerB

  DT: DeTerminer

  NN: NouN

  You can see that a sentence has a syntactic pattern that can be used to split a paragraph into sentences.
- Build a model of possible syntactic tree of a sentence. By saying a model I mean a file/database that contains syntactic build of sentences.

  **Example**: a model can contain the following lines:

  PP VB DT NN  -->  (I eat an apple)

  VB ADJ NN  -->  (create new methods)

  To construct your model you can analyze many sentences (the larger is your set of sentences the more accurate will be your system). You can use a [corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus) built by your own self.
- Once you have build your model, you can start writing your program. The main lines of your algorithm will be:

  1- Receive the input paragraph (as an input or file).

  2- Apply Stanford Parser to produce the syntactic tree of the paragraph.

  3- Start splitting your paragraph based on on the comparison of parts of the paragraph with previously constructed syntactic tree (your sentences model --> your pattern)

  You will need to measure the [similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187303/how-to-measure-syntactic-similarity-between-a-query-and-a-document) of a part of the paragraph with a sentence-model.

I tried to give you an idea/approach on how to do what you want to do.

Probably you will need to work with [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Natural Language Toolkit).

Comment: Thanks ZimYth. I am trying the approach.I will post the code and updates once i get somewhere. At this point i am learning the NLTK to use parsing based on Syntactic tree model.

Comment: @MangalPandey here is a wonderful book for stduying natural language processing (Speech and Language Processing by Daniel Jurafsky and James H. Martin) http://www.deepsky.com/~merovech/voynich/voynich_manchu_reference_materials/PDFs/jurafsky_martin.pdf . I just LOVE this book!!, If this is a helpful answer maybe you can aprove it ;)